# how to create a full width with no label select element in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

In a form I would like to use a full width  element.
I don't need any label, is this possible?

This select is used to store a list of elements that are filled by a controller.
I have tried without using a  but it does not change anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the tag  and set the  size with `max-width: 100%; width: 100%`.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectModel" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%">
    <ion-option value="c">Fist Item</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="e">Second Item</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Regards.